# How to deal with connection pooling and DAOs?

Tags: java, datasource, jndi, connection-pooling

I am learning about `JDBC` connection pooling and it sounds relatively easy to get a `DataSource` instance using `JNDI`:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/myDB");
```

All the tutorials I found show this code in one object only, but my question is how to use a `DataSource` when I have several `DAO` objects needing to fetch data from a DB.

1. **Is it ok to use the code above for connection pooling on every new `DAO` object's constructor?** I think the same `DataSource` will be returned every time, much like a Dictionary Singleton would do, holding a single `DataSource` and returning it, or am I wrong and will it return a different `DataSource` every time and use different pools, defeating my purpose?
2. **Should I hold that `DataSource` in a Singleton and only run the `JNDI` search once or is the search overhead neglectable and this is a silly optimization?**

Comment: Have you tried https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/ or https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/ ? They provide out of the box connection pooling functionalities without re-writing from scratch. Sorry, may not be an answer to your question. Just thought of let you know. Good luck!

Comment: I will use the solution inside of tomcat 8, but it's not related to the question at all, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is it ok to use the code above for connection pooling on every new DAO object's constructor? I think the same DataSource will be returned every time, much like a Dictionary Singleton would do, holding a single DataSource and returning it, or am I wrong and will it return a different DataSource every time and use different pools, defeating my purpose?

The same DataSource object ought to be returned each time.  If it's not literally the same object, then it ought to at least share the same underlying connection pool.

> 2. Should I hold that DataSource in a Singleton and only run the JNDI search once or is the search overhead neglectable and this is a silly optimization?

The search overhead of JNDI is negligible compared to performing operations on a remote database, so it's not necessary to cache the DataSource object.

Comment: Is this how people use it on DAOs? Or is it there some other famous pattern?

Comment: First I should ask, are you running on a Java EE app server or no?

Comment: I am running on tomcat 8...But why does this matter? Shouldn't this be decoupled from the underlined platform?

Comment: not necessarily, app servers provide value that should be taken into account when writing code.  In this case tomcat provides connection pooling so the application (you) doesn't need to worry about it.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I understand, after I configure tomcat to use connection pooling, the rest is pretty much transparent....so even if I chance tomcat for something else, the JNDI call to retrieve the DataSource on my DAO should remain the same

Comment: My worries are not about tomcat, just the best way to fetch the same DataSource on all the DAOs, and if there's a recommended pattern to use.... The tomcat JDBC pooling binding with the DataSource is pretty much independent and decoupled as far as I have seen

Comment: correct.  I was just making sure there is some layer below you (in this case app server) handling the connection pooling.  Since that is the case, the DAO pattern you've described is sufficient (i.e. looking up a new DataSource each time)